# size transition on resizable textarea

Tags: css, resize, textarea, less, css-transitions

I've implemented my textarea, which is shown/hidden with transition animation on hover on its master element:

my LESS:

```
.my-hidden-textarea textarea{
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    resize: none;
    .transition(~"width 0.3s, height 0.3s, left 0.3s");
    .box-sizing(border-box);
}
.my-hidden-textarea:hover textarea{
    left:-338px;
    width:350px;
    height:100px;
}
```

I want to keep the resize option for the textarea, but the problem is that when I resize the textarea, it overrides the size given by the css and when I hover out, the textarea remains opened (no size change).

I tried to add !important, resp:
        width:0px !important;
        height:0px !important;
    ....
        width:350px !important;
        height:100px !important;
however, now the area is not resizable any more (even with resize:both).

It happens in Firefox 29.0, I haven't tested other browsers but I expect similar problem.

Is there a pure CSS3 solution, or do I have to use javascript for such animation? thanks in advance.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/ec9pC/)

Comment: Could you create a demo?

Comment: http://store.amniverse.net/test.htm - try resizing the textarea and hover out then

Comment: http://store.amniverse.net/test2.htm - the textarea can't be resized althrough it has the resize control visible

Comment: am I missing something?  I've never seen rules like your `.transition` and `.box-sizing`?  the CSS `resize` property does nothing unless the overflow property is something other than visible, which is the default for most elements. So generally to use this, you'll have to set something like `overflow: scroll;`...as per [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/r/resize/)

Comment: ahh, just noticed "my LESS".

Comment: Sorry for the "resize" confusion, It remained in my style from previous experiments. actually, resize:both is default for textarea, you don't need any setting of overflow. This is not the problem, the problem is that manual resize behaves like inline change of style - overrides size changes by changing css class.

Comment: Why don't you try something like this [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/ec9pC/1/)

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, when you hover out, the text area should collapse back to it's original state.  Your Fiddle works for me in Chrome and Firefox.  And I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @MarmiK: I don't know if its got anything to do with browser versions, but even in your fiddle I can see the same problem. When you hover on the text area and resize it before hovering out, the text area stays as is even after hovering out. It doesn't go back to its original state.

Comment: @Harry I believe that was OP's problem.. but yet waiting for his reply :)

Comment: @MarmiK try opening your fiddle, manually resizing the textarea (drag bottom right corner) and hover out. It won't hide.

Comment: The correct solution is actually already written below, thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a possible solution for your problem have been given at https://stackoverflow.com/a/23618098/1596547.

Set the `max-height` and `max-width` properties to zero for the normal state and to a large value for the hover state.

Your Less code:

```
@import "./mixins/vendor-prefixes.less"; //from Bootstrap 3 
.my-hidden-textarea
{
    textarea {
        width:0px;
        height:0px;
        max-height: 0px;
        max-width: 0px;
        .transition(~"width 0.3s, height 0.3s, left 0.3s");
        .box-sizing(border-box);
    }
    &:hover textarea {
        left:-338px;
        width:350px;
        height:100px;
        max-height: 30em;
        max-width: 300em;
        resize: both;
    }
}
```

The preceding Less code will compile into the following CSS code:

```
.my-hidden-textarea textarea {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  max-height: 0px;
  max-width: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.3s, height 0.3s, left 0.3s;
  -o-transition: width 0.3s, height 0.3s, left 0.3s;
  transition: width 0.3s, height 0.3s, left 0.3s;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.my-hidden-textarea:hover textarea {
  left: -338px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100px;
  max-height: 30em;
  max-width: 300em;
  resize: both;
}
```